# python lmfit "object too deep for desired array"

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, scipy

I am trying out lmfit and using as an example problem below. In this example, I am simply solving for x in a system Ax = y. Here A is a 3*2 array, y is a 3*1 array. I have declared all of them as arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters

A = np.array([1,2,-1,3,-2,5])
A = A.reshape(3,2)
y = np.array([12, 13, 21])

def residual(params, A, y, eps_y=1):
    x = params['x'].value
    y_hat = np.dot(A, x)
    return (y - y_hat)/eps_y

x = np.array([0,0])
params = Parameters()
params.add('x', x)
out = minimize(residual, params, args=(A,y))
print out.value
```

When running this I get an error: "ValueError: object too deep for desired array". 
I have found instances of similar problems researching here and on web. In general, most often reason cited is that A, x and y should be arrays and not matrix. Also in some solutions, x and y are asked to be a kept as a vector with shape (len(v),). Above is already in compliance with these suggestions but I am still getting "ValueError: object too deep for desired array".

I have wasted quite a bit of time trying to solve this problem and am stumped now. Any help on this will be very welcome.

Comment: Please show the traceback (i.e. the complete error message).  It should tell you exactly which line is raising the exception, along with the calls preceding it.  That should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks for your comment. Ashwin has been able to point me in the right direction and I have been able to make it work. Though as I mentioned in my comment to him, optimization is extremely slow for A of size 1300*30, y of size 1300*1 and x of size 30*1. Don't know if there is some other library that I can use for non-linear constrained inversion providing different methods to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `Parameter` is here:

http://newville.github.io/lmfit-py/parameters.html#Parameter

It specifically states that the value of a parameter must be a numerical value, and not an `array` of any kind. So instead of doing:

```
x = np.array([0,0])
params.add('x', x)
```

do:

```
params.add('x0', 0)
params.add('x1', 0)
```

and then change the residuals function to:

```
def residual(params, A, y, eps_y=1):
    x0 = params['x0'].value
    x1 = params['x1'].value
    y_hat = np.dot(A, [x0, x1])
    return (y - y_hat)/eps_y
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I read the documentation for Parameter class but then assumed that how can it not take a vector as input. I recoded to automatically assign a vector as params for minimize() as well as automatically decompose it into optimization parameters in residual function. It is working now. Optimization is very slow though for an A of size 1300*30, y of size 1300*1 and x of size 30*1. I was expecting better performance. Quite disappointed after trying to make it work for nearly half a day.

Comment: Is the decomposition taking up most of the extra time, or is `np.dot` taking up most of the time?

Comment: Ashwin thanks for asking. I checked and minimize() is taking nearly 4 secs per optimization compared to ~ 0.00013 secs taken by np.dot for each time it is being called in "residual" function. Thus, on an average it is taking ~ 33000 calls to residual() to find least square solution to above described problem for an A of size of 1300*30, y of size 1300*1 and x of size 30*1. The size of problem itself is around 5000 such observations to solve for, thereby total inversion time will be around 5.5 hrs :(.